# Нужно добавить функционал добавления images через десктопное приложение

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю приложение магазина одежды и мне необходимо в аккаунте администратора добавлять айтемы с описанием товара размерами и соотвественно фото.чтобы было пустое место фотки, нажимая на область открывался диск с фолдерами для выбора фотки.  делаю на **wpf**, но ничего не нашёл для решения.

Comment: OpenFileDialog? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-open-common-system-dialog-box

Comment: exactly! thanks